# dynamically putting form fields using append in my form but not getting values ( the name in URL ) while submitting the form in jquery

Tags: javascript, dynamic, input, append

I am trying to insert input field in my div `onclick` of check box. and it is working but when i submit the form the value is not received to me of that input box

**check box**

```
<form action="{{ url('product_uplo') }}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <tr>
            <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="ELarge" name="pro_size[]" onclick="a('ELarge')" value="ELarge"> Extra Large</label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Large" name="pro_size[]" onclick="a('Large')" value="Large"> Large</label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Medium" name="pro_size[]" onclick="a('Medium')" value="Medium"> Medium</label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="Small" name="pro_size[]" onclick="a('Small')" value="Small"> Small</label>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" id="ESmall" name="pro_size[]" onclick="a('ESmall')" value="ESmall"> Extra Small</label>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    <td>
                      <div id="set"></div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <input type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
        </td>
      </tr>
</form>
```

**JQuery code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function a(extra){
    if($('#'+extra+'').is(":checked")){
      $('#set').append("<div id="+"price"+extra+"><label>"+extra+"</label><input type='text' name='pro_price["+extra+"]' class='form-control' placeholder="+extra+" /></div>"); 
    }else{
      $('#price'+extra).remove();
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I submit the form the url is like this

> http://www.asggas.com/product_uplo?dat=pro_type=Girls+Cloth&pro_name=asadsfd&brand=sadf&Material=sadf&pro_color=sdf&pro_des=sadf&pro_size%5B%5D=ELarge&pro_size%5B%5D=Large&pro_quantity=5446&galary%5B%5D=

it doesn't pass `pro_price[Elarge]` ...

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching to much i got the answer. because of i am using table tag it's now sending the data. so remove the table tag and it will work